# Can't update to rails 5 because of ruby version

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am planning to run ruby 2.3.1 version with Rails 5 on Mac OSX.

**1** I installed rbenv then install ruby version 2.3.1.

```
rbenv version
2.3.1 (set by /D/testProject/.ruby-version)
```

**2** Update gem

```
gem update --system
Latest version currently installed. Aborting.
```

**3** System ruby version:

```
ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin15]
```

But when i run `gem update rails`, i got

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    activesupport requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

So my question is how to make the gem update rails according to rbenv ruby version, not system version? Then i can update to Rails 5.

or

Do i have to update my system version of ruby to update to Rails5.

**EDIT**

I have ran `rbenv local 2.3.1` (.ruby-version was created) already. But still can't update to Rails5
Thank you!

**EDIT**

```
which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I update my system version of ruby solved the issue.

```
brew install ruby
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command:

```
$ rbenv local 2.2.2
```

(this will generate a .ruby-version file)

Comment: Sorry i mean i can't upgrade.

Comment: Can you add the output of the following command: `which ruby`?

Comment: which ruby
/usr/bin/ruby

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have already updated ruby using something like

> sudo gem update --system

You can then set the rvm gemset lst to use the global version(s) installed.

```
 rvm gemset list

 rvm gemset use global -save
```